# Swagger UI does not render contents through HTTPS when using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core

Tags: c#, .net, azure, function, swagger-ui

I have set the `ForceHttps` option in my custom `OpenApiConfigurationOptions` but still getting the contents only in http when running it locally thru `http://localhost:7071/api/swagger/ui`. Here is my custom configuration:

```
public class OpenApiConfigurationOptions : DefaultOpenApiConfigurationOptions
{
    public override bool ForceHttps { get; set; } = true;
    public override OpenApiInfo Info { get; set; } = new OpenApiInfo()
    {
        Version = "1.0.0",
        Title = "OpenAPI Document ",
        Description = "An adapter",
        Contact = new OpenApiContact()
        {
            Name = "N/A",
            Email = "N/A",
            Url = null,
        },
        License = new OpenApiLicense()
        {
            Name = "MIT",
            Url = new Uri("http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT"),
        }
    };

}
```

I am using `"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi" Version="1.5.1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You can directly run your Function to use **`Https`** like below:-***

I directly created one `Http with OpenAPI Trigger` `.net 6.0`  and ran it with below command from **Visual Studio Terminal**:-

[image]

```bash
func start --port 7071 --useHttps
```

[image]

[image]

**Reference -**
[How to enable azure function https easily when do local test - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62453695/how-to-enable-azure-function-https-easily-when-do-local-test) by Cindy Pau